# (jQuery) Tabs inside foreach-loop -> Problems with multiple Tabs on one page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a foreach-Loop and every loop should include a jQuery-Tab-Element.

My code is too long and unstructured so I can't post it here.

Now I wrapped the jQuery-Code inside the loop and gave all the tabs elements the same ID but it doesn't work.. On which elements do I have to give an ID?

I am using the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".tabs li a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".divcontent").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: Provide plunkr or jsfiddle example, please

Comment: "and gave all the tabs elements the same ID" - ids are supposed to be unique.

Comment: Like Pasha said an ID should be unique to a given element

Comment: I don't get it working right now but this is the structure: http://jsfiddle.net/L5fth7pc/2/   I am sorry I wrote wrong. The elements have the same ID, but the id of the tabs of the main loop is different, otherwise it does not work. My problem is not the tabs, but it is the following; that they are not loaded correctly because there is the main loop and so there are many tabs on one page and when you click for example the button in the 2nd loop result, the first content div is opened, but not the second one.

Comment: YOU CAN'T HAVE ELEMENTS WITH THE SAME ID.  You can use a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. sample --- http://jsfiddle.net/john_12/pjocttns/

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$("ul li  a").click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().addClass("current");

    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");

    var tab = $(this).attr("href");

    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");

    $(tab).fadeIn();
});
```

});

Comment: Thank you, this works but doesn't solve the problem.. When I loop the whole tab-wrapper now, then always one .tab-conent div is closed.. Or in other words: It appears that only one div can be open at one time on one page. I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjocttns/1/

Comment: This one here works correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/RwPps/188/  But has anyone an idea how I can achieve it that I have unique IDs even when I loop a whole part?

Answer (score 1):

// Try this  i change your Html Markup

..

    ..



    
    content...
  

  

    content...2

//  Change the Script. make it shorten.

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(".tabs li a").click(function(event) {

```
event.preventDefault();

$(".contentdiv").css("display", "none");

$(".tabs li").removeClass("active");

$(this).parent().addClass("active");

var tab = $(this).attr("href");

$(tab).fadeIn();
```

});
});

// Same Css codes

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your answer, but I got it working like this now: http://jsfiddle.net/RwPps/188/ This works correctly finally and can be used for loops.